# Spring Framework Upgrade to 5.3 from Spring Framework 4.0.2 and Spring Security From 4.0.2 to 5.8.9 . using JAVA 8 . getting error in weblogic

Tags: spring, upgrade

I am trying to update my application from Spring Framework Upgrade to 5.3 from Spring Framework 4.0.2 and Spring Security From 4.0.2 to 5.8.9 . I am using java 8 , My Project is getting built in eclipse oxygen but when deploying in oracle weblogic i am getting following error
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BeanFactoryReference

this is my image of dependency jar files in eclipse that i upgraded
[eclipse spring jar dependency snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jL8a.png)

I was trying to deploy this application after sucessful build but in oracle weblogic while deploying was getting status :Failed

Comment: For starters stop m,ixing versions. Currently you are mixing version 4.02, 5.3.27 and 5.3.29. That is trouble waiting to happen.